Do I want 5kw or 10kw heat strips for an 800 square foot home in Florida?
Some quotes 5kw, others 10k heat strips. Getting condenser & furnace replaced. Not getting heat pump. Going with heat strips. 800 sq ft cmu 1952 home average insulation.
Should i go 5 or 10kw? Oh yea this is florida, but i turn on heat when it touches mid to low 70sF

This is Florida. You MUST have air conditioning. So why not have a heat pump and get heat at the same time? Save energy. More importantly, save money, particularly since you run the heat a lot more than many other people would. And Florida is the perfect place for a heat pump for heating because you simply don't have any days that a modern heat pump can't handle.

Why on Earth are you refusing to get a heat pump in the year 2024? Newsflash: 2024 heatpumps are a good half-century of technical development ahead of the 1974 models

I would check on the running electric costs of the strips to a heat pump.  Do not know Florida electric costs, but heat strips/space heaters tend to burn through money like nothing.

At 65°F a modern heat pump will use about 1 KW to produce as much or more heat than 10kW in a heat strip, but you do you...

A heat pump simply is an air conditioner with a reversing valve.  It's not like a separate appliance.  So it's not a large incremental cost on an A/C you're buying anyway, and now your winter electric bills drop like a stone.   But if you're doing heat strips, why scrimp?  Load it up to the limit of your service, the strips are cheap.

To all the criticism for heat strips over Heat pump.   In Fla often the price for a heat pump is far greater than an air conditioner and heat strips. Especially in an older built home that does not have the electrical system designed for the energy needs.  Often in the small homes an air conditioner and "Furnace" which is a wall unit is the cheapest way to go, especially if you are retired and on a fixed income.

10KW is what you want.
I have a condo in Fla. 820 sq Ft.  Has 10KW heat strips and works great for the tenant.

Care to comment on the down vote?  I provided input based on real world facts.
